# Wrapping smarty tags in single quotes

Tags: javascript, syntax, smarty

I want my Smarty template with this code:

```
<h3><a href="http://www.test.com" onclick="RemoteLogger.logGAEvent('Homepage', 'ClickTop10', {$playlist->title|purify});">{$playlist->title|purify}</a><\
/h3>
```

to produce this:

```
<h3><a href="http://www.test.com" onclick="RemoteLogger.logGAEvent('Homepage', 'ClickTop10', 'desiredstring');">desiredstring</a><\
/h3>
```

I've attempted any number of ways of inserting single quotes around the smarty variable ({$playlist->title|purify}) to no avail. I always get an unquoted string like this:

```
<h3><a href="http://www.test.com" onclick="RemoteLogger.logGAEvent('Homepage', 'ClickTop10', desiredstring);">desiredstring</a><\
/h3>
```

Any thoughts about how to get this tag wrapped is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just put the quotes in the HTML template, around the Smarty tag like so:

```
<h3>
  <a href="http://www.test.com"
     onclick="RemoteLogger.logGAEvent('Homepage', 'ClickTop10',
                                      '{$playlist->title|purify}');">
    {$playlist->title|purify}
  </a>
</h3>
```